# python requests module post to php script

Tags: php, python, post, https, python-requests

I need to upload some .csv file into a self signed https apache server. 
My https server is running PHP. My client is running a python script to POST files into the https server. PHP.ini has 20M for upload_file and POST_max_size directives with no extra whitespace. The file i need to upload is only 4kilobytes

**my python script:**

```
import requests
username = "user"
password = 'password'
myfile = "/full/path/to/myfile.csv"
url = "https://www.mydomain.com/file_upload.php"

files = {'file': open(myfile, 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, auth=(username, password), verify=False)
print r.text
print r.status_code
```

I receive a status code 200 but the file is not in the destination server
I believe the error is somewhere in my file_upload.php

$_FILES['userfile']['name'] was the name i was using when i was posting the file from a HTML form which is not the case anymore. 
I believe i am missing something due to my lack of understanding of the $_FILES variable in PHP - **How the file-id should look like when not posting from a form?**

```
<?php

$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file-id']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file-id']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
error_log(print_r($_FILES['file-id']['error']), 3, $error_log_file);

?>
```

**my apache error.log reports the following PHP notice**

[Thu Jun 05 09:35:19.120760 2014] [:error] [pid 8030] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49207] PHP Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0

[Thu Jun 05 09:35:19.124625 2014] [:error] [pid 8030] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49207] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/file_upload.php on line 8

[Thu Jun 05 09:35:19.124673 2014] [:error] [pid 8030] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49207] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/file_upload.php on line 11

[Thu Jun 05 09:35:19.124686 2014] [:error] [pid 8030] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49207] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/html/file_upload.php on line 12

**Permission**
my www folder is chown -R www-data.www-data

Comment: First error I see, in PHP script you use "file-id" but in request "file". That is why notice appered. I don't know python, but I think your request is not multipart form.

Comment: Thanks, that is just because i renamed file to file-id in this thread to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

When you want to upload a file using the python module requests read the file as follow:

```
files = {'testname': open(myfile, 'rb')}
```

now in the receiving PHP file the $_FILES variable must be used as follow:

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['testname']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['testname']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

basically the name for the $_FILES index is the NAME of the label you give when you read your file name in python.